# How to show a materialize modal from a partial in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

New to rails and I am confused on how to show a materialize modal that's been placed in a partial.
I'm creating a **Pokedex** in a table and I am creating a `'pokemon party'` feature for it. I have been able to add to the party from the main home screen table and remove pokemon from the party page, but I want to add a confirmation modal for the remove.

I have been looking at examples for the past few hours but as they're either using Bootstrap or jQuery or `'leanModal'` in Materialize I am confused, and the Materialize docs don't use leanModal and jQuery. I just want to use Materialize, vanilla JS and Ruby of course ha.

I want to be able to press the link_to, to open the modal, then run the remove_from_party on 'AGREE'

So, here is my

**party.html.erb**

```
      <% @party.each do |pok| %>
        <tr>
          <td> <%= image_tag pok['image']%></td>
          <td> <%= pok['id'] %>  </td>
          <td> <%= pok['name'].capitalize %> </td>
          <td> <%= link_to 'FIND OUT MORE', pokemons_show_path(pok['name']), :class => 'find-out-more' %> </td>
          <td> <%= link_to 'REMOVE FROM PARTY', pokemons_party_remove_modal_path(pok['name']),  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#party_remove_modal', class: 'waves-effect waves-green btn'}  %>
 </td>
          <td> <%#= link_to 'REMOVE FROM PARTY', pokemons_party_remove_path(pok['name']), :class => 'remove-from-party', method: 'delete' %> </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

This is my route

```
get '/pokemons/remove/:name', to: "pokemons#show_party_remove_modal", as:"pokemons_party_remove_modal"
```

This is my controller method for the showing the modal

```
  def show_party_remove_modal  
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :partial => '../javascript/party/remove.js.erb' }
    end
    @pokemon_name = params[:name]
  end
```

This is in my application.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
});
```

This is my partial for the modal

```
  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="party_remove_modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Remove from Party</h4>
      <p>Are you sure you would like to remove <% @pokemon_name.capitalize %> from your party?/p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= link_to 'AGREE', pokemons_party_remove_path(@pokemon_name), :class => 'modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn', method: 'delete' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My remove.js.erb partial

```
var instance = M.Modal.getInstance('party_remove_modal');
instance.open();
```

Honestly quite confused as there's so many solutions but none seem to match the new docs. I can't get the modal to even appear. **ALL** tips/constructive criticism welcome. If you need more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your error but Materialize's. Take out the undeclared options variable:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
});
```

With options:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
   var instances = M.Modal.init(elems,{
       dismissable: true
   });
});
```

I can't speak for the rest of your code - but I know for sure that the options variable will break your JS.

Also, the way you are trying to open the Modal isn't quite right. `getInstance` takes an element, not a selector:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#myModal');
var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(elem);
instance.open();
```

You don't even need `getInstance` - if you only have 1 modal, or you know which modal you want to open, you get get it by index from the `elems` variable you set in the init:

```
instances[0].open();
```

Comment: so I won't be able to include {dismissible: true} ?

Comment: dismissable is already true by default - but if you wanted to include options, I've edited the answer. https://materializecss.com/modals.html#options